# Is ping.c source code already present in ubuntu server? Where is it located?

Tags: server, 22.04, ping

I am using ubuntu server 22.04.1 LTS on raspberry pi 4. Is the ping.c source code already present in the OS and if yes, where is it located?

Thanks!
Divya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiled `ping` binary is provided by the `iputils-ping` package.

The source code is in the corresponding *source package*. Source packages are not included with a stock install of Ubuntu. You must add those separately using tools provided by the `apt-src` package.